# How to use $.extend() with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I'm trying to make a script to use multiple values in window.location.hash but i'm having a problem with the $.extend() function of jquery

I've tried two ways, but both didn't work out.

```
var MultiHash = {
    params: {},

    getHash: function () {
        var hashString = document.location.hash.replace('#', '').split('&');

        for (var i=0; i < hashString.length; i++) {
            var key = hashString[i].split('=')[0];
            var value = decodeURIComponent(hashString[i].split('=')[1]);

            // First way
            var a = {key: value};

            // Second way
            var a = {};
            a[key] = value;

            $.extend(params, a);
        }

        return params;
    },

    ...
}
```

Is anyone seeing the problem?

Comment: Can you use console.log() to see what you variable **a** contains? And put the $.extend(params, a) outside of the for {} loop

Comment: Note that you need to run `decodeURIComponent` on keys, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you should write :

```
 $.extend(this.params, a); or you cant access param
```

there may be other issues.

**EDIT**

it makes sense you return a instead of this.params in my opinion.

```
$.extend(a,this.params);

return a
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems wrong with what you're trying to do. The first of which being a reference problem as the params variable for that object should be referenced as `this.params`. The second problem being that you are not saving the result of the object extension. All of this occurs in the following line:

```
$.extend(params, a);
```

It should read something like this instead:

```
this.params = $.extend(this.params, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
var MultiHash = {
    params: {},

    getHash: function () {
        var hashString = document.location.hash.replace('#', '').split('&');

        var a = [];
        for (var i=0; i < hashString.length; i++) {
            var key = hashString[i].split('=')[0];
            var value = decodeURIComponent(hashString[i].split('=')[1]);
            a.push(key + ":'" + value + "'");           
        }

        $.extend(this.params,(new Function("return {" + a.Join(",") + "}"))());

        return this.params;
    },

    ...
}
```

Comment: as Joseph said, there's a reference problem...`this.params` not just `params`